# Printing a column name inside lapply function

Tags: r, lapply

I have searched through the archives but have not found a suitable answer. I am a beginner and please excuse my ignorance if I am posing a very elementary query. I am trying to get the apply function to print the column names while processing through a data frame. I understand that lapply converts the column of data frame to vector, but is their way to print the column name while printing output. Like in the following example

```
   > mydata<-data.frame(matrix(rep(c(1:2),times= 50),20,5))
   > colnames(mydata)<-letters[1:5]
   > lapply(mydata[,2:4],function(x){CrossTable(x,mydata[,5])})
```

I want the output to show the column name it is processing while printing the output table. It only prints only "x"  right now in the contingency tables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `CrossTable()` function is contained in the `descr` package, it seems that the argument to `dnn` gives the row and column names in the crosstabulation. The trick is to get `lapply` to read both the names and the data. `names(mydata)[2:4]` gives the names; `mydata[, 2:4]` is the data. The syntax for `lapply` is:

```
lapply(x, FUN, ...)
```

`FUN` is applied to each element of `x`, and `...` allows optional arguments to be passed to `FUN`. Thus, both `names(mydata)[2:4]` and `mydata[, 2:4]` can be passed `FUN`.

```
mydata<-data.frame(matrix(rep(c(1:2),times= 50),20,5))
colnames(mydata)<-letters[1:5]

library(descr)

lapply(names(mydata)[2:4], 
   function(dfNames, dfData) {
      return(CrossTable(dfData[[dfNames]], mydata[,5], dnn = c(dfNames, "mydata[,5]")))
}, mydata[, 2:4] )
```

The function operates on each element in `names(mydata)[2:4]`, and the data file is passed as an additional parameter. This way, the relevant column (`dfData[[dfNames]]`) and the name of the relevant column (`dfName`) are available to `CrossTable.`

```
[[1]]
   Cell Contents 
|-------------------------|
|                       N | 
| Chi-square contribution | 
|           N / Row Total | 
|           N / Col Total | 
|         N / Table Total | 
|-------------------------|

===============================
          mydata[,5]
b             1       2   Total
-------------------------------
1            10       0      10
          5.000   5.000        
          1.000   0.000   0.500
          1.000   0.000        
          0.500   0.000        
-------------------------------
2             0      10      10
          5.000   5.000        
          0.000   1.000   0.500
          0.000   1.000        
          0.000   0.500        
-------------------------------
Total        10      10      20
          0.500   0.500
===============================

[[2]]
   Cell Contents 
|-------------------------|
|                       N | 
| Chi-square contribution | 
|           N / Row Total | 
|           N / Col Total | 
|         N / Table Total | 
|-------------------------|

===============================
          mydata[,5]
c             1       2   Total
-------------------------------
1            10       0      10
          5.000   5.000        
          1.000   0.000   0.500
          1.000   0.000        
          0.500   0.000        
-------------------------------
2             0      10      10
          5.000   5.000        
          0.000   1.000   0.500
          0.000   1.000        
          0.000   0.500        
-------------------------------
Total        10      10      20
          0.500   0.500
===============================

[[3]]
   Cell Contents 
|-------------------------|
|                       N | 
| Chi-square contribution | 
|           N / Row Total | 
|           N / Col Total | 
|         N / Table Total | 
|-------------------------|

===============================
          mydata[,5]
d             1       2   Total
-------------------------------
1            10       0      10
          5.000   5.000        
          1.000   0.000   0.500
          1.000   0.000        
          0.500   0.000        
-------------------------------
2             0      10      10
          5.000   5.000        
          0.000   1.000   0.500
          0.000   1.000        
          0.000   0.500        
-------------------------------
Total        10      10      20
          0.500   0.500
===============================
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is old, but I came across the same problem and wanted to share my approach, although it violates to some extent the *apply idea. The upside is: you can integrate anything in the loop. So I needed to run an ANOVA on 2 output variables, depending on columns I looped through with lapply, get the p_values to annotate the plot and create multiple plots side-by-side.
The core is that it combines a for-loop with lapply

```
for (i in 0:10){
i<-i+1
lapply(df[i],function(x) {
  myfactor<-names(df)[i] #gets the column name
  anova_model_a<-lm(a~x,df) #needed to run ANOVA per column
  anova_model_b<-lm(b~x,df) #needed to run ANOVA per column
  tab_aov_a<-tidy(summary(anova_model_a)) #proper result table
  tab_aov_b<-tidy(summary(anova_model_b)) #proper result table
  labels_a <- data.frame(drv = "1", label=c(round(tab_aov_a$p.value[2],4))) #needed for labelling the graph. I only had 2 groups for comparison
  labels_b <- data.frame(drv = "1", label=c(round(tab_aov_b$p.value[2],4))) #needed for labelling the graph
  fig1<-ggplot(df,aes(x,a))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    ggtitle("a")+
    geom_text(data=labels_a,aes(x=drv,y=12,label=label),colour="blue",angle=0,hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5,size=5)+
    xlab(myfactor)

  fig2<-ggplot(df,aes(x,b))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    ggtitle("b")+
    geom_text(data=labels_b,aes(x=drv,y=6,label=label),colour="blue",angle=0,hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5,size=5)+
    xlab(myfactor)
  arrangement<-grid.arrange(fig1,fig2,nrow=2)
  print(arrangement)
})
}
```